# MediaWiki: how to hide users from the user list?

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

I've set up Mediawiki 1.15.1 for a client who has added two users by mistake. They now want to hide these users from the user list.

It seems this is done via the `$wgGroupPermissions` array with `$wgGroupPermissions['suppress']['hideuser'] = true;`, but it isn't at all clear what entry this needs for the hiding to work, or whether a new group ('hidden' or whatever) has to be created first with `$wgAddGroups['bureaucrat'] = true;`.

For now, I've added the two users to be hidden to the 'Oversight' group which explains 'Block a username, hiding it from the public (hideuser)', but they still appear on the Special:ListUsers page.

At a loss as to how the MediWiki arrays alter options displayed in the interface, so far I've added this to `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['suppress']['hideuser'] = true;
$wgAddGroups['supress'] = true;
```

Or - since they haven't actually added anything to the wiki - could they simply be removed from the MySQL users table - although MediaWiki warns against this?

Has anyone else done this successfully?

Update - this is a hole in MediaWiki admin (although there are workarounds). See [this thread on MediaWIki Users](http://www.mwusers.com/forums/showthread.php?14399-Hiding-a-user-from-the-users-list-or-deleting-them&p=47785) and the note to the reply below.

Answer (score 1):

Install the ["merge and delete"](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Merge_and_delete) extension.

Comment: I've seen that, but was trying to avoid the extra work. No other way?

Comment: Hoggwild on the Mediawiki 'mwusers' forum responded with a new script - after I'd posted the only available options and realised that this function is not easily available (say you create a new user who then wants to back out). See: http://www.mwusers.com/forums/showthread.php?14399-Hiding-a-user-from-the-users-list-or-deleting-them&p=47785